# Does "$A$ centralizes $B$" mean that $A \leq C_G(B)$ and $B \leq C_G(A)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm studying the centralizer of a subgroup $A \leq G$, defined as the set of all the elements of  the group $G$ that commute with all elements of $A$,

$$C_G(A)= \{g \in G \mid ga=ag, \forall a \in A \}.$$

If $B$ is another subgroup of $G$, I've read that when $A \leq C_G(B)$, $A$ is said to centralize $B$. But if $A$ centralizes $B$, is it also true that $B \leq C_G(A)$?

Comment: It just follows logically. $A\leq C_G(B)$ means that every element of $A$ commutes with every element of $B$. Clearly this is the same as saying that every element of $B$ commutes with every element of $A$, i.e $B\leq C_G(A)$.

Comment: Yes, I wanted confirmation, I'm new to group theory. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, we have that for any subsets $X$ and $Y$ of a group $G$,

1. $X\subseteq Y$ implies $C_G(Y)\leq C_G(X)$.
2. $X\subseteq C_G(C_G(X))$.

You should try prove them. They are easy, and important.

Combining them, if $X\subseteq C_G(Y)$, then $Y\subseteq C_G(C_G(Y))\subseteq C_G(X)$.

Thus, we conclude that
$$X\subseteq C_G(Y) \iff Y\subseteq C_G(X).$$

This shows, by the way, that taking centralizers yields a [Galois connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_connection?wprov=sfti1) from the subsets of $G$ to itself. Since $C_G(X)=C_G(\langle X\rangle)$ (another good exercise to establish), we also get a Galois connection from the partially ordered set of subgroups of $G$ to itself.

This connection plays an important role in the Chermak-Delgado measure and lattice of a finite group, for example.